# Encoding .wav to .flac through cygwin: error can't open input file: Invalid argument

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I'm using bash via cygwin on a windows machine to batch-convert several hundreds of wav-files to flac. I wrote a simple script to read each file from a txt-file containing a directory-print I did earlier, convert the linuxpaths to windowspaths and using FLAC to encode the files.

```
#!/bin
IFS="$(printf '\n\t')"
(for wav in $(cat path/wavfiles.txt)
do
  winwav= $(cygpath -w "$wav")
  flac --best --verify "$winwav"
  sleep 30
done)
```

The path conversion seems to be working fine: bash expands out the path correctly to a windows path for FLAC to use, but FLAC keeps spitting out the following error message:

> ERROR: can't open input file : inavlid argument

I tried encoding the files with a similar script windows batch file and it worked fine, so the files aren't the problem. I searched a lot of sites, including this one and the FLAC-helppages, but I can't seem to find any information concerning this error message. Probably something silly I overlooked, it usually is.
Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the space in `winwav= $` so it's: `winwav=$`  Also fix your hashbang from `#!/bin` to: `#! /bin/bash`

Comment: Check your code through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: That seems to have done it, thanks a lot!